# display alert only once in an hour if it happens

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't know where I am going wrong but its been hard for me to implement. Basically, an error can happen for any reason but I want to alert the message only once in fifteen minutes. So for e.g. if it happens at 7:02AM, I display the alert. If there is an error, at 7:10AM, i don't display. But if it displays after 8:02, I display it again then the cycle continues.

Right now, it simply alerts the message no matter what I do.

```
  lastTimeErrorWasDisplayed = 0;
  displayError() {

    let vm : any = this;

    // get the current time
    const timeNow = new Date().getTime();

    const hoursToWaitBeforeNextToastr = 1;

    const difference = timeNow  - this.lastTimeErrorWasDisplayed
    var hours = (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    // show we show toastr now?
    if (
      hours > hoursToWaitBeforeNextToastr
    ) {
      this.lastTimeErrorWasDisplayed = timeNow;

      setTimeout(() => {
        vm.toastr.warning(
         "error",""
        );
      });


    }
  }
```

the setTimeOut is necessary due to the application requirements but even without it, it still shows the error no matter when it happened and when the last time it was displayed.

Comment: You could debounce an RXJS Subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var startTime = new Date('2019/06/30 16:00');
var timeNow = new Date();
var difference = timeNow.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
var resultInMinutes = Math.round(difference / 60000);

if (resultInMinutes >= 15) {
 // your code
}
```

You could also change the if-condition to 60 if you want to check for every hour.